# Extend RedCloth via Redmine plugin?

Tags: ruby, redmine, textile, redcloth, redmine-plugins

I'm new to Ruby/Redmine/Redcloth but I'm trying to achieve the following:
The default way to build a link in Textile is "foo":http://bar. However, 90% of the day I use Atlassian products, which use [foo|http://bar] as link markup.

To keep everything a bit uniform I'd like to implement this in Redmine via a plugin. However, it appears that you can't change the macro syntax so instead I'll have to look into extending RedCloth to accept this form of inserting links.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Thank you and merry christmas,

Dennis

Answer (score 1):

You might consider switching to one of the two Markdown plugins (one is Markdown Extra-like, based on Bluefeather), which are a bit more similar in link style, although not the same as what you are used to.  Since you use SO, though, you're obviously familiar with it.

Otherwise you'd have to write a full plugin, for which either of the plugins I've mentioned would serve as a good model.  Best of luck.

Comment: Hi Binary Phile, thanks for your answer! One thing that sucks about it that it depends on rdiscount and it seems it circumvent the wiki formatter in a weird way in order to invoke markdown formatting. I rather build something build on a regular expression that outputs it in proper html. Any idea how to do that?